# passing values stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using react native and react native navigation 4, i need to pass some values from my api to another page but im getting undefined

this is my father code

```
  const Sol1Form = ({navigation: {navigate}}) => {

  const [request, setrequest] = useState();

  async function getList() {
    const vKindSearch = 1;
    const vCreationUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
    const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/GetRequestController.php`,{ vCreationUser, vKindSearch})
    console.log(data.request);
    setrequest(data.request);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, []);
    return (
        <ScrollView>
         <View style={styles.Lcontainer}>
            <FlatList 
            columnWrapperStyle={styles.listContainer}
            data={request}
            keyExtractor= {(item) => {
              return item.solicitude_id;
            }}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
              <View style={styles.tarjeta }>
                <View style={styles.solicitudview }>
                  <Text style={styles.solicitud }>Id de la Solicitud: {item.solicitude_id}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.card }>
                  <Text style={styles.clave}>Nombre: {item.full_name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.clave}>Comentarios: {item.comment}</Text>
                </View>
                <View >
                <TouchableOpacity  style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}  onPress={() => navigate('Irregular',{ewe:item.solicitude_id})}>
                  <Text style={styles.loginText}>Atender Irregularidad</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
          )}}/>
      </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

here i need to pass the `item.solicitude_id`

on my child page i have this code

```
const ImgPicker = ({onSubmit,navigation,route}) => {
     const [value] = useState(route.params.ewe);
     console.log("akiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", value );}
```

the child code do more things but i wanted to console.log value but i got undefined, idk what im doing wrong, i hvae seen many tutorials and im setting everything right calling the navigates and that stuff
any help would be awesome

edit

here is where imgpckr is called

```
   const Solicitudes1 = ({navigation}) => {
    const {state, guardarIrre} = useContext(Context);
  return(

    <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.head}>
                <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/Logo-Pequeño.png')} /> 
            </View>
            <View style={styles.backContainer}>
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Ionicons style={styles.back} name="ios-arrow-back" size={27} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.textIniciar}>Nueva Solicitud</Text>
                </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        <ScrollView >
        <IrregularForm
            onSubmit = {guardarIrre}
        /> 
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: have you tried recovering the param with this? navigation.getParam(
      'ewe',
      'some default value',
    )

Comment: it throws me an error, undefined is not an object (evaluating navigation.getParam)

Comment: can you please add the code where your ImgPicker is called

Comment: done, but the file is called IrregularForm

Comment: IrregularForm should receive navigation as a prop so as ImgPicker, <IrregularForm
            onSubmit = {guardarIrre} navigation={navigation}
        />

Comment: it worked thanks charlie, you are a god to me

Comment: Great!, i'm glad it worked, let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the navigation props your component or screen should have access to it, if it's declared in react navigation then they will get the prop by default, the other way is to pass it as a prop to the component:

```
<IrregularForm onSubmit = {guardarIrre} navigation={navigation} />
```

This way your IrregularForm component will have access to it, and so your ImgPicker will also have access and can receive the navigation prop.

```
<ImgPicker navigation={navigation} />
```